# Getting rid of "Tell us the account you want to use to open autodiscover.xml" which pops up in Word (Office 365)

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, windows-11

Every time I open Word, this pops up:

[image]

When I type in the e-mail address associated with my personal account and hit Next, the window disappears, only to reappear the next time I open Word.

I recently switched from a enterprise account for Office 365 to a personal account. There is no hint of the enterprise credentials under the Windows Credential Manager. I have already checked OSPP.VBS per [this link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/remove-microsoft-365-apps-for-enterprise/fd352421-c700-49f2-9d0b-75dc1353be75) and have already checked HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity\Identities. The enterprise credentials, as far as I know, shouldn't be remaining in my computer.

How can I get rid of this pop-up window?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a try of settting the two registry keys then restart Office.

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\office\16.0\outlook\autodiscover
DWORD:ExcludeExplicitO365Endpoint
Value=1

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\outlook\autodiscover
DWORD:ExcludeExplicitO365Endpoint
Value=1

Answer (score 0):

Try the Microsoft 365 uninstall support tool and select to remove all versions:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/uninstall-office-from-a-pc-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8

I also made sure all office folders were deleted including the profile folder where the old *.ost file is stored.